# how to assign id field in form_label CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My question is in the title, how to assign id field in form_label CodeIgniter.

I have form label :

```
echo form_label('Titre', 'titre');
```

Because I need 'id' to delete this label with javascript.

Thanks,

Vincent.

Comment: `label` elements should not have an `id` attribute, however they can have a `for` attribute which you can use for deletion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$attributes = array(
'class' => 'mycustomclass',
'style' => 'color: #000;',
'id'    => 'id',
);
echo form_label('What is your Name', 'username', $attributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

codeGodie is right labels should not have id instead to text box or any other input field you can add id as

```
<?=form_input(array("name"=>"some","id"=>"some","value"=>set_value("some"),"placeholder"=>"some","class"=>"Some"))?>
```

plz read the documentation of https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html for further reference